# Postfix server sends mails properly, but not recive them

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, webmin, virtualmin

I set up my mail server with Webmin/Virtualmin with Postfix couple days ago. Server lives on EC2 instance.
Everything was working just fine. Mails were being send and I recived them properly as well. I didn't only pass MX records tests. Since that time the only thing I messed up with were MX Records in DNS Records - those change allowed me to pass tests on mail-tester. I also had some prompt about updating packages, so I did update them. After that I tested my mail server (but only sending message - it was ok).
Today I wanted to use mailbox once again (to warm up my IP) and noticed that I can send email, but didn't recive any. However emails send from my mailbox to my mailbox (the same address, so internal) are being recived. So only emails from outside are not coming through.

What I tried:

-checked my Security Group on EC2 instance - It's just fine - I allow port 25 and all other from everywhere (except SSH :22 of course). So it doesn't look like firewall issue (especially that it was working and I didn't mess up with them)

-Checked postconf -n and I realized there are Warnings:

> postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
>   postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
>   postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
>   postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
>   postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
>   postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions

So I found this thread: [Warning `undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions` when `postconf -n`](https://serverfault.com/questions/952776/warning-undefined-parameter-mua-) 
  sender-restrictions-when-postconf-n **and I got rid of Warnings** by adding to my main.cf file lines:

> smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions, mua_client_restrictions, mua_helo_restrictions
>   mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
>   mua_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
>   mua_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit

That way Warnings disappeared but problem persists. I still cannot recive any mails form outside.

EDIT: Solved. The problem was invalid dkim record.

Comment: Great that you solved it, but please don't edit your solution into your question. Post it as an answer and accept it, otherwise your question will pop up again and again because it is not marked as "solved" in the system. It is perfectly fine and encouraged to accept your own answers.

Comment: My bad. Lesson learned. Thank you for feedback!